# Create custom survey with expiration date in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to create survey using SharePoint 2010 which will have expiration date. After this date, no user should be able to respond to that survey. But the data of previous responses should retain. What will be the best option to achieve this?

Regards,
Shruti

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the only thing you could do is change the permissions for the survey to remove contribute access. But this will have to be done manually.